# TypeError: C3Ghost.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c2'

Tags: python, yolov5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test310\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Data\ghostnetyolo\yolov5-6.1-slimming\prune.py", line 487, in run_prune
    pruned_model = ModelPruned(maskbndict=maskbndict, cfg=pruned_yaml, ch=3).cuda()
  File "E:\Data\ghostnetyolo\yolov5-6.1-slimming\models\yolo.py", line 263, in __init__
    self.model, self.save, self.from_to_map = parse_pruned_model(self.maskbndict, deepcopy(self.yaml), ch=[ch])  # model, savelist
  File "E:\Data\ghostnetyolo\yolov5-6.1-slimming\models\yolo.py", line 551, in parse_pruned_model
    m_ = nn.Sequential(*(m(*args) for _ in range(n))) if n > 1 else m(*args)  # module
TypeError: C3Ghost.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c2'

Process finished with exit code 1
```